# How do I count how many times I have columns that are populated?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I have a decent sized spreadsheet (9,000 rows, and 150 columns). The columns indicate the various weeks of a year a product (the row) generated a sale. I want to count how many instances there are with consecutive weeks where a sale is recorded. For instance, let's say a product has generated a sale in Week 2, 3, 4, 7, 22, 23, 24, 25. What formula do I need to say "there were 3 instances where weeks had sales"(the 3 instances being Weeks 2-4, Week 7, and Weeks 22-25).

I don't need to count how many weeks had sales, I need to count how many times there were sales back to back (or back to back to back, etc) and for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

Thank you for your assistance thus far. I have included an image which is a sample of what I am working with. If we use Product L as an example, it's easy enough to count the amount of weeks that are populated by a 1. The struggle I am having is counting how many instances of consecutive weeks. I hope the visual helps to see what I am working with.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to count the instances a number has appeared on the column, use the formula such as =COUNT(B2:B9000)

Now, if you needed to count how many times a certain expression appeared, please use this format for the following:

specific letter without any other characters, regardless of capitalization
=COUNTIF(C2:C9000,"f")

...=COUNTIF(C1:C7,"2") will count all the number 2, but will not include "2A" or "32" values in any of the cells,
If you need the entire table to be scanned =COUNTIF(A2:ET9000,"f")

However, if you simply want to count the cells that contains any form of values (numbers or letters) in a column, use the formula =COUNTA(C2:C9000).

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a new column with the *sales-group*, that is the same for each consecutive week (calendar week *CW*.

That is:

```
if this week = last week + 1 then: group of last week
 else group of last week + 1 (aka next-group)
```

Let's say your week is stored in column C and the week group in column D, then
cell D1 = 1
cell D*n* = **if(C*n* = C*n-1*, D*n*, D*n* + 1)**

According to your example:

| C | D (formula) | D (result) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | if (3=2+1, 1, 1+1) | 1 |
| 4 | if (4=3+1, 1, 1+1) | 1 |
| 7 | if (7 =3+1, 1, 1+1) | 2 |
| 22 | if (22 =7+1, 1, 1+1) | 3 |
| 23 | if (23 =22+1, 1, 1+1) | 3 |
| 24 | if (24 =23+1, 1, 1+1) | 3 |
| 25 | if (25 =24+1, 1, 1+1) | 3 |

The formula MAX(D) is is the number of weeks with consecutive sails.